# Why do all plots open in new windows when I use JavaGraphics?

Tags: plotting

I want to open only one plot in new window.

When I use `` <<JavaGraphics` ``  all plots open in new windows.

I put `` <<JavaGraphics` `` before one last plot but it works for all plots.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the notebook interface?

Answer (score 14):

Graphics has an option, `DisplayFunction`, that determines what happens with the graphic.  The default setting is `DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction`, and in a normal Mathematica session, `$DisplayFunction` is `Identity`.  This means that nothing special is done with the graphic, and (since Mathematica V6) the frontend just renders the output as a graphic (instead of literally showing `Graphics[...]`.)

When you load `JavaGraphics`, the definition of `$DisplayFunction` is redefined, to a function `` System`Private`JavaDisplay `` that creates a bitmap of the graphic and puts it up in a new Java window.  Since `$DisplayFunction` has been changed globally, this is done for all graphics that are generated after `` JavaGraphics` `` has been loaded.

If you only want to create a separate window for a single plot, you can specify the `DisplayFunction` option for just that plot, like so:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, DisplayFunction -> CreateDialog]
```

instead of loading `` JavaGraphics` ``.